# How are tags sorted on SE?

Tags: discussion

I was editing a question of mine which had the `Google-Chrome` tag. I added the `bash` tag and after editing it was before the `Google-Chrome` tag instead of behind it as shown in the edit window when editing. So that means that StackExcange has some kind of sorting program that sorts it. How are they sorted? Alphabeticly? Most used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tags are sorted by the number of questions in each.

Most to Least.

Go to the home page, and find a question with a lot of tags, hover, and it will show stats. You will see that they are arranged in this order.

Comment: so on the home page it is the same sorting as in the question?

Comment: For tag-ordering to be displayed to the users, I do believe so. How it is sorted on the back end, I have no idea.

Comment: allright, I understand